# Expo deep linking

Tags: expo, deep-linking

I am trying to make a deep link open the Expo development app for days already. I tried every combination I could think of.

In Firebase I added my custom domain and correctly set up a custom prefix as `/app`
I created a "dynamic link" to `https://somedomain.com/app/go` and instructed it to open in the android app if installed, or open the Play Store if not.

Next, I thought it will be easier to set up on Android and test with a simulator. [I followed Expo's docs](https://docs.expo.io/workflow/linking/#deep-links-on-android) and added this to my `app.json`. The app is running on the **expo client app**.

```
"intentFilters": [
  {
    "action": "VIEW",
    "data": [
      {
        "scheme": "https",
        "host": "*.somedomain.com",
        "pathPrefix": "/app"
      }
    ],
    "category": ["BROWSABLE", "DEFAULT"]
  }
]
```

I pasted `https://somedomain.com/app/go` into a text message on an android AVD simulator.

Now... according to the Expo docs:

> You simply need to add intentFilters to the Android section of your
> app.json. The following basic configuration will cause your app to be
> presented in the standard Android dialog as an option for handling any
> record links to myapp.io

When I click on the link in Messages, I am only presented with the options to open in Chrome, copy, and share.

When I click the link, it:

1. Opens Chrome with the URL
2. Goes back to Messages and shows a loader
3. Opens Google Play Store

What am I doing wrong?

Next, I am hoping I may be able to test it with ios. The [Expo docs on ios Universal links](https://docs.expo.io/workflow/linking/#universal-links-on-ios) is even more confusing. Are they referring to a published app? Would this work in development using the expo client? What is the Apple App ID? Does it mean I first need to have the app on the App Store to test deep linking with Expo and ios?

This seems to be a very niche subject as there are literally no tutorials (written or video) about Expo and deep linking... and this is a very basic need for any app. Isn't it?

Comment: For your ios questions this post details everything that helped me get it working for ios: https://stackoverflow.com/a/71543147/13543938