# Implementing Universal links for react native expo

Tags: reactjs, react-native, expo, deep-linking

im trying to implement universal links for react native expo, i did all the steps from the documentation but the problem lies with hosting i believe, my website is hosted with hostinger. when i checked the website using Branch.io 's validator it gives me this error.

[the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4BK8I.png)

i made a .htaccess file and put this in it but it didn't work either

<Files "apple-app-site-association">
ForceType 'application/json'

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Here is if anyone wants the complete guide that worked for me: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67193187/ios-universal-links-using-expo-is-not-working?rq=2